# GridBagLayout gridheight constraint not affecting result

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I am working on a Java Swing Project using the GridBag Layout. I am trying to make two panels that have the same width and are aligned horizontally, but have different heights.

Like this:
[image]

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Mega extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Mega();

    }

    public Mega() {

        Dimension minDimension = new Dimension();
        minDimension.width = 800;
        minDimension.height = 800;

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.add(mainPanel);

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainPanel.add(topPanel, constraints);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 3;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, constraints);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

With this code, the bottom panel should be three times as tall as the first, since it takes up three rows, versus the top row that only takes up one row. However, what I get looks like this.

[image]

It doesn't look like the gridheight = 3 constraint is making a difference, since both panels have the same height. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gridHeight` will have no affect because there are no more rows for it to expand over (think of `gridWidth` and `gridHeight` as "expand across"), instead, either provide better sizing hints from your components or play with the `weighty` property

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Mega extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Mega();
            }
        });

    }

    public Mega() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() {
            // This is done for demonstration purposes
            // it would be better for the child components
            // to provide appropriate sizing hints
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 800);
            }
        };
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.add(mainPanel);

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 0.25;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        mainPanel.add(topPanel, constraints);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 0.75;
        mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, constraints);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```